# Handling imporper data during deserialization when using Symfony Serializer Component

Tags: symfony, json-deserialization

I am new to the Symfony serializer component. I am trying to properly deserialize a JSON body to the following DTO:

```
class PostDTO
{
    /** @var string */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

The controller method as follows:

```
/**
 * @Route (path="", methods={"POST"}, name="new_post")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function create(Request $request): Response
{
    $model = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), PostDTO::class, 'json');
    // call the service with the model
    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

My problem is that I wanted to handle business-validation after the body was deserialized. However, if i specify an invalid value for the name, such as `false` or `[]`, the deserialization will fail with an exception: `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotNormalizableValueException: "The type of the "name" attribute for class "App\Service\PostDTO" must be one of "string" ("array" given).`.

I do understand that it is because I intentionally set  `"name": []`. However, I was looking for a way to set the fields to a default value or even perform some validation pre-deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the proper way to handle this. That exception was thrown because the serializer was not able to create the `PostDTO` class using the invalid payload I have provided.

To handle this, I have created my custom denormalizer which kicks in only for this particular class. To do this, I have implemented the `DenormalizerInterface` like so:

```
use App\Service\PostDTO;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\ExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class PostDTODeserializer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    /** @var ObjectNormalizer */
    private $normalizer;

    /**
     * PostDTODeserializer constructor.
     * @param ObjectNormalizer $normalizer
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $type === PostDTO::class;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $data
     * @param string $type
     * @param string|null $format
     * @return array|bool|object
     * @throws ExceptionInterface
     */
    public function supportsDenormalization($data, string $type, string $format = null)
    {
        // validate the array which will be normalized (you should write your validator and inject it through the constructor)
        if (!is_string($data['name'])) {
            // normally you would throw an exception and leverage the `ErrorController` functionality

            // do something
        }

        // convert the array to the object
        return $this->normalizer->denormalize($data, $type, $format);
    }
}
```

If you want to access the `context` array, you can implement the `DenormalizerAwareInterface`. Normally, you would create your custom validation and inject it into this denormalizer and validate the `$data` array.

Please not that I have injected the `ObjectNormalizer` here so that when the data successfully passed the validation, I can still construct the `PostDTO` using the `$data`.

PS: in my case, the autowiring has automatically registered my custom denormalizer. If yours is not autowired automatically, go to `services.yaml` and add the following lines:

```
 App\Serializer\PostDTODeserializer:
        tags: ['serializer.normalizer']
```

(I have tagged the implementation with `serializer.normalizer` so as it is recognized during the deserialization pipeline)